# Incorporating Item quantity in the transactions for Apriori algorithm

Tags: r, data-mining, pattern-recognition, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I was working on a simple recommender system, i started off with apriori algorithm using arules in R. To my surprise i got 0 rules for when support was greater that 0.0001, which is too low a value for support. I figured out that the reason for this could be that the duplicate items in each transaction are being removed. I tried to solve this by setting remove duplicates as false:

```
df = read.transactions("transactions.csv",sep = ',',rm.duplicates = FALSE)
```

But that didn't work and i got the following

```
Warning message:
 In asMethod(object) : removing duplicated items in transactions
```

So is there a way to solve this, or is there a better way to consider the quantity of each item in every transaction in the code? Is there a better option in python or any other language? It would be great if anyone could help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

The support is based on the number of transactions.

The quantity of an item thus does not matter for the support by definition.

Your problem is probably that you did not preprocess your data well enough. For association rules, it usually seems to be necessary to work with product *groups* or *classes* rather than individual product codes. I.e. find rules with "beer" and "milk" rather than "Wilmaukee's worst 12 oz. can 24 pack" and "FUGGIES UnderNites Diapers, Size 4, 56 ct, BIG PACK". Merging such overdifferentiated products dorsimprove the support.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I did the data preprocessing and my transactions are like popcorn, coke,... each row denoting a unique transaction, and the problem is that when i remove duplicate items(which R doing even if i don't want to), i am getting 0 Rules for any decent support and I am getting like 15-20 rules for a support of 10^(-4). So i thought the way to get rules with decent support, is by considering quantity(duplicates) of items. Is there a better way to look at this, any help would be really appreciated.